# How to create a folder for each item in a directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble making folders that I create go where I want them to go. For each file in a given folder, I want to create a new folder, then put that file in the new folder. My problem is that the new folders I create are being put in the parent directory, not the one I want. My example:

```
def createFolder():
    dir_name = 'C:\\Users\\Adrian\\Entertainment\\Coding\\Test Folder'
    files = os.listdir(dir_name)
    for i in files:
        os.mkdir(i)
```

Let's say that my files in that directory are Hello.txt and Goodbye.txt. When I run the script, it makes new folders for these files, but puts them one level above, in 'C:\Users\Adrian\Entertainment\Coding.

How do I make it so they are created in the same place as the files, AKA 'C:\Users\Adrian\Entertainment\Coding\Test Folder'?

Comment: Use normal slashes in paths even for Windows (the same way the Unix souls do). Python accepts them happily. But definitely use the `os.path.join()` and the related functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os, shutil

for i in files:
  os.mkdir(os.path.join(dir_name , i.split(".")[0]))
  shutil.copy(os.path.join(dir_name , i), os.path.join(dir_name , i.split(".")[0]))
```

Answer (score 2):

`os.listdir(dir_name)` lists only the names of the files, not full paths to the files.  To get a path to the file, join it with `dir_name`:

```
os.mkdir(os.path.join(dir_name, i))
```

Comment: So I changed the os.mkdir line to what you suggested, but now I'm getting an error that I cannot create a file when that file already exists. They're not the same though, because one's a folder and the other is a text file, right? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @AdrianAndronic directory names and filenames can't overlap. (just fire up the windows file browser and try to create a directory with the same name as a file or vice-versa...Windows shouldn't let you do it).